# Are questions duplicates when two different but valid answers exist?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513650/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-line-of-c-sharp-code), I answered and that is (correctly) marked as duplicate. The [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265412/set-timeout-to-an-operation) is targeting the same subject and thus the first one is a duplicate.

However if you are looking at the point of time both questions are asked, there's a difference of almost 3 years. During this time technology has changed. In the specific example, I am using the .NET TPL to solve the same problem in an shorter and easier way. The TPL wasn't available at the point of time the first question has been asked. Both questions have their valid answers, only that the later one describes an more up-to-date way of solving the same problem.

This made me thought if duplicate questions are valid under some circumstances, especially if their answers differ in quality and the actual approach in a way that the question subject may be affected. In the previously mentioned example the first question could be interpreted as *"How to set the timeout for an operation using TPL?"* and the second one as *"How to set the timeout for an operation using threading?"*.

Should I cast a reopen vote for this question? What do you think?

Related question: [Closing posts as duplicate of very old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95011/closing-posts-as-duplicate-of-very-old-questions)

Answer (score 1):

If questions are the same then yes, they are duplicates. If both have valid answers, once one of them is closed, flag for merge so the answers are not lost.

If you are about to ask the same question again, either make it different by pointing out you want the answer to use new technology, or start a bounty with:

> Current answers are outdated
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

as a bounty reason.

Note than age is not an only criteria when deciding which question to close. Closing old question in favour of new one is OK, if new one is clearly written better and have better answers. Only when quality is similar, age should decide.