# What should I do with question that has been answered on another site?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

I have reviewed the following question and answer

[What's the policy on marking questions as duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88506/whats-the-policy-on-marking-questions-as-duplicates)

As part of the community, what should I do when I find questions that have been answered on another site?

Answer (score 0):

Question can only be closed as duplicates of each other if they are on the same site.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you cannot close as duplicate of something offsite, onsite questions should be closed as duplicate when they, and I'm not trying to be funny here, are duplicates of another question (on the same site)

Notes: maybe, if there is an obvious duplicate, it is offtopic because of that other site? Also, you can answer if you have an answer, and even answer AND vote to close as duplicate if you want ;)